# Healthy riding for asthmatic

Tags: long-distance

I have asthma and find it very hard to ride for a very long time without tightness in my chest. Is this safe for me? I have knee pain as well and I find bike riding helps with the knee pain, but asthma is a different story.

Comment: This is between you and your doctor -- we generally don't give medical advice here.  But I had asthma as a child and overcame it, in part, by riding a bicycle -- around and around a 2-block circuit, up and down a moderate hill.

Comment: For the knee pain you need to be sure that your seat is not set too low -- having the seat too low can cause knee injury.

Comment: Search the site a bit - we have plenty of answers on knee pain which tends to be bike setup, or possibly joint wear with age.  Either way bike fit.

Answer (score 1):

I can not give any advice, but I can present my personal story and experience. When I was a child, I was diagnosed with asthma. I needed to take a lot of medications in order to fight against asthma. I stayed also a lot of nights in hospital. At the age of 11, doctors suggested my to try endurance sports. I have chosen cycling. In fact, I really had a lot of problems with breathing in my first two years of cycling career. I needed to take Ventolin (Salbutamol) every training. During the years, situation became much better. After some years of training, I became competitive enough on a national level. In line with this, I have never faced any major problems with asthma again. I am racing now Ironman triathlons without any medications. I only sometimes have problems with breathing when there is a mix of hot and cold weather. Usually, when Autumn is transitioning in Winter I need to take one or two inhalations of Ventolin. Anyway, I also avoid riding in fog.